# EJB Invocation failed on component by java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, invocation

I have a method in EJB Bean

```
@Override
public void checkReqPermission(List<String> req, MyContext context) 
              throws AccessControlException, Exception
{
 if(notAllowed)
 throw new AccessControlException("Unauthorized Access : User is 
              not permitted to execute command(s)");
}else{
...}
```

In the other side I need to catch this **ACE** for further statement execution.

When I call this method what does happens? I have lot of exception traces in server.log

```
 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (ajp-space-52786b8b6d90/192.168.27.143:8009-4) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ##EJB##  for method public abstract ###CLASS## ##METHOD###(Params,java.util.List,Context) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized Access : User is not permitted to execute command(s)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:191) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.notSupported(CMTTxInterceptor.java:299) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:212) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]

########################CUSTOM CLASSES###################

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:67)
at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:48)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:408) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.sso.ClusteredSingleSignOn.invoke(ClusteredSingleSignOn.java:374) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:473) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:454) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2036) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]

 Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: Unauthorized Access : user1 User is not permitted to execute command(s)

########################CUSTOM CLASSES   BEAN AND INTERFACE ###################

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]

########################CUSTOM CLASSES###################

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:123) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:235) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
... 58 more
```

I dont print this exception trace any where.

What does it means? Does indicate access for that method is not allowed or my custom exception?

If it is access not allowed for that method means how can I use this **ACE**?
or it is my custom exception means How can I block this exception trace in server log?

Thanks in advance:).

Comment: Why don't you throw your custom exception and handle it. Why do you want to throw a security exception?

Comment: @Patton I have created new custom exception. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The messages you see in your log is because `java.security.AccessControlException` is an unchecked exception (it is a RuntimeException).
When a `java.lang.RuntimeException` is thrown from the ejb method, the container will

1. roll back the transaction
2. discard the EJB Bean instance
3. Throw the **RuntimeException** wrapped by `javax.ejb.EJBException` to the
   client.

In JBoss every **EJBException** is logged.

When you know what kind of exceptions you expect in your client layer, you have to unroll the **EJBException** to dig into the real reason, and show it to the user if it's meaningful to her. These kind of exceptions would be specialized runtime exceptions you defined (let's say  **AccessControlException** extends **RuntimeException**).

Digging into the real reason is a simple method:

```java
Throwable unrollException(Throwable exception, Class<? extends Throwable> expected){
    
    while(exception != null && exception != exception.getCause()){
        if(expected.isInstance(exception)){
          return exception;
        }
        exception = exception.getCause();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In other case, when a `java.lang.Exception` is thrown from the EJB method, you obviously have to declare it in the method's signature with the throws keyword.  the container will:

1. the transaction gets commited
2. the exception is rethrown to the client.

In EJB terms a checked exception is an **ApplicationException**. The name indicates that this exception means a problem, the application developer is aware of.

See also:

- [Best practices in EJB exception handling](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ejbexcept/)
- [Exception-Handling Antipatterns](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983543#ejb3)

Comment: The second link (https://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns#ejb3) is broken.